# Recover SSH Key from GITHUB

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I had an ssh key in git. Now that I reinstall my operating system, how can I recover my old github ssh key and put it in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa?

I tried to generate a new password but in this case I would have to re-register my public key again in both gitlab and github, right?

Comment: For the second question, yes, you can add a new key to GitHub. You can also simply delete the old key, and then no one can use it there (even if existed elsewhere, your machine got stolen, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a backup of your old key, then it was probably lost when you reinstalled your OS, since typically doing so reformats the hard drive.  GitHub wouldn't have your private key, since that's stored only on your computer.  GitHub holds only the public portion of the key, which can be used to verify connections, but not to make them.

However, it's fine to simply generate a new SSH key and add it to GitHub and GitLab, removing the old key.  Part of the idea behind SSH keys is that they can be rotated more easily than other types of credentials if needed.

The easiest way to do that is to run `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`, which will generate you a Ed25519 key, which is the preferred key form these days.  You can then add it to GitHub and GitLab as normal by copying the contents of `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` into the web interface.